# Image smoothBitmapContent doesn't work?

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

recently I got a jagged image problem when scaling. I set my image components smoothBitmapContent true, and it works properly the first time, but if I reset the source, the images return jagged. It seems like the smoothBitmapContent property has been changed to false, but it doesn't work even if I set it to true in run time. Anyone knows how to fix this? Thanks.

Here's is my code:

```
<custom1:SmoothImage id="MJCard_3_36" x="286.5" y="56.65" scaleX="0.66" scaleY="0.83" smoothBitmapContent="true"/>

MJCard_3_36.source = seabedPicArr[index1-1][index2-1][index3-1];
```

I simply use a custom Image-extended class and switch smoothBitmapContent on, and I set the image's source in run time.

Comment: Please show your code. You're giving us nothing.

Comment: Hi, the codes are added above, don't know if it's clear.

Comment: What about the code for `SmoothImage`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable smoothing with dynamically loaded images, you need to listen to Event.COMPLETE on Image. Then get content (it should be Bitmap) and set smoothing to true:

```
var image:Image = new Image();
image.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);
image.source = ...

function onLoaded(event:Event):void
{
    event.target.content.smoothing = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, maybe I mentioned it wrong, I use the images as UI components, but I set it's source in run time. I've added my codes.

Comment: If your component has Image inside, it should listen to "complete" event and enable smoothing like above (you can use property `smoothBitmapContent` to control it.) If not... I don't know :)